How to include square brackets in regression and stargazer output
I am currently writing a short r code to run a regression but one of co-variate (CAR[-11,0]) contains special characters, and it reports error "object 'CAR[-11,0]' not found". I have tried to cover CAR[-11,0] with '`' symbol.Here is my r code to run the regression.
library(stargazer)
set.seed(123)
n <- 200
df <- data.frame(
  risk1 = rnorm(n),
  risk2 = rnorm(n),
  `CAR[-11,0]` = rnorm(n),
  `CAR[-27,0]` = rnorm(n),
  `CAR[-18,0]` = rnorm(n),
  lev = rnorm(n),
  grow = rnorm(n),
  fcf = rnorm(n),
  fage = rnorm(n),
  roe = rnorm(n),
  top1 = rnorm(n),
  dual = rnorm(n),
  board = rnorm(n),
  comp = rnorm(n),
  soe = rnorm(n),
  year = sample(2000:2006, n, replace = TRUE),
  f006v_pub001 = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  check.names = FALSE
)
main_regression_1_0_A <- lm(risk1 ~ `CAR[-11,0]` + factor(year) + factor(f006v_pub001), data = df)
stargazer(main_regression_1_0_A, type = "text")

I have tried replace all of special characters (including[ ] , -) with underscore. It works, but I really want to keep them in variable name to make them readable. Here is the r code with underscore:
set.seed(123)
n <- 200
df <- data.frame(
  risk1 = rnorm(n),
  risk2 = rnorm(n),
  CAR_11_0 = rnorm(n),
  CAR_27_0 = rnorm(n),
  CAR_18_0 = rnorm(n),
  lev = rnorm(n),
  grow = rnorm(n),
  fcf = rnorm(n),
  fage = rnorm(n),
  roe = rnorm(n),
  top1 = rnorm(n),
  dual = rnorm(n),
  board = rnorm(n),
  comp = rnorm(n),
  soe = rnorm(n),
  year = sample(2000:2006, n, replace = TRUE),
  f006v_pub001 = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  check.names = FALSE
)
main_regression_1_0_A <- lm(risk1 ~ CAR_11_0 + factor(year) + factor(f006v_pub001), data = df)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(main_regression_1_0_A, type = "text")


Use check.names = FALSE
df <- data.frame(
  risk1 = rnorm(n),
  risk2 = rnorm(n),
  `CAR[-11,0]` = rnorm(n),
  `CAR[-27,0]` = rnorm(n),
  `CAR[-18,0]` = rnorm(n),
  lev = rnorm(n),
  grow = rnorm(n),
  fcf = rnorm(n),
  fage = rnorm(n),
  roe = rnorm(n),
  top1 = rnorm(n),
  dual = rnorm(n),
  board = rnorm(n),
  comp = rnorm(n),
  soe = rnorm(n),
  year = sample(2000:2006, n, replace = TRUE),
  f006v_pub001 = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  check.names = FALSE
)


data.frame() checks the names with special characters and replaces them with dots. see names(df) of your original code

Thank you Ric, it does work well. But now I got another issue related to stargazer.
When I run stargazer(main_regression_1_0_A, type = "text") to output the result, I got an  error:
Error in if (is.na(s)) { : the condition has length > 1
How can i solve it?

perhaps need to update R https://gist.github.com/alexeyknorre/b0780836f4cec04d41a863a683f91b53
